# Passing dynamic objects from client-side to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, client-server

**Passing dynamic objects from client-side to C#**

*hello friends,*

i'm searching for passing a dynamic data, whatever data sent which is **value type** or **reference type** or **both**,

lets see a example as simple

> **client-side**

**1st request**

```
var model = {
   Id: 10,
   Name: 'John'
   Active: true
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: '@Url.Action("MethodName_ToDo")',
    data: JSON.stringify(model)
});
```

**2nd request**

```
var model = {
   Email: 'm@m.net'
   CurrentSalary: 1500,
   CurrencyType: 1
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: '@Url.Action("MethodName_ToDo")',
    data: JSON.stringify(model)
});
```

**3rd request**

```
var id = '1e575923-d6cf-447e-9163-f7885655e4f5';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: '@Url.Action("MethodName_ToDo")',
    data: {Id : id}
});
```

> **server-side**

```
public JsonResult GetData(dynamic model)
{
   // my code here...
}
```

---

**Question:**

- I need a way to receive a dynamic data.
- Is it possible to send dynamic data from client-side(using jquery ajax) to Server-side C# ?!

Please let me know if you have any idea about this question.

> **Note: I will not vote down, for any answer**

---

i use this for call server-side

```
var data = {
    Name: 'Sam',
    Age: "26"
};
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/Home/PostData",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: (xhr, tt, tm) => errorHandler(xhr, tt, tm)
});
function errorHandler(xhr, tt, tm) {
    console.dir(xhr, tt, tm);
};
```

---

[image]

Thank you so much, *UW*.

Comment: One way I could achieve this is accept input as string.. And use something like Newtonsoft jobject. so the input string can be parsed as jobject

Comment: I think that should work if you add `[FromBody]` to the parameter.

Comment: @Mandy , not working, values coming equal null now ;(

Comment: @Crowcoder also not working value coming equal {object} ;(

Comment: It will normally be very difficult to use an object without knowing what its properties are anyway. If this worked how would you proceed? Regardless, assuming example #1, what do you get if you write `var theName = model.Name` after adding the `[FromBody]` attribute?

Comment: @Crowcoder the result is : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', because the object equal null

Comment: Did you use example #1, the one that has `Name` ?

Comment: It works for me. [See my MVC 5 project where I take a `dynamic` parameter.](https://github.com/crowcoder/Dynamic59808926/blob/master/Controllers/DynamicController.cs). When I hit this controller I can access any property that was in the JSON sent to it.

Comment: can you provide me, how you call it, i mean how you call api function using javascript(jquery ajax)

```hostName/Dynamic/PostData```

Comment: I used Postman to call it. Since your question is about the controller, the client would be irrelevant. But maybe your controller is OK and your jquery is the problem. Open the browser dev tools to the Network tab while you make that ajax call and look at the request body.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I would say thank you for communication with me, but still not working can you please try to call API name 'PostData' with a basic JQuery Ajax(Ajax call) request, please?

Comment: and let me see, on Github

Comment: I'm trying so much in this subject but without any result.

Comment: Are you sure about method name you are using in controller matches  the one in Ajax call? Also try adding content type in the Ajax call to application/json

Comment: @Crowcoder, i will edit question, check request
check 'i use this for call server-side'

Comment: I updated the github repo with (basically) your code and it works just fine.

Comment: @Crowcoder, umm I don't use API application, I using a .Net Framework MVC

Comment: can you help me, how i can solve it in MVC not in API

Comment: The project combines MVC and API. Instead of fighting against the framework you should consider using an api controller when you want to return data and an MVC controller when you want to return a view.

Comment: @Nancy try this and see if it helps you in your usecase         
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8081/Home/PostData",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "model": JSON.stringify(data) },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: (xhr, tt, tm) => errorHandler(xhr, tt, tm)
        });

you should find the input in model[0] as string